# NSUSer defaults and swiping the application off ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, appdelegate

All,

I just cannot find an answer to this question. The settings View Controller needs to shown once on startup ONLY.   So when you download the app from the App Store / test flight.

I have it correct, so it runs it first, thats fine. 
when you have finished with the settings page it goes to the main page and when you move the app to the background it carries on from where it left off. thats fine.. But... When you swipe the app away by double pressing the home button and pushing the app up to remove (ios7) it goes back to the settings screen again but it should carry on from where it left off.

So in my App Delegate, I have :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  stringForKey:@"SettingsShown"];
    NSLog(@"%@", savedValue);
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.outtonightapp.com"];
    [reachability startNotifier];

    NSUserDefaults *settingsscreen = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [settingsscreen registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"firstTime", nil]];
     //BOOL firstTime = [settingsscreen boolForKey:@"firstTime"];
    BOOL firstTime = [settingsscreen boolForKey:@"SettingsShown"];

    if (!firstTime) {
    //if ( firstTime==YES) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SettingsShown"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SetUpNav"];
    }

    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
```

This did work until I had to recreate my settings VC.. any advice would be great.

Comment: Why do you use `"firstTime"` in the *default* user-defaults and `"SettingsShown"` for the value?

Comment: Droppy, I give up with this... Can you please advice ?

Comment: Well I'm not sure it will make a difference but look at the keys you use in your `registerDefaults` line.  Change it from `"firstTime"` to `"SettingsShown"` and see if it helps.

Comment: It's look like you never read the last status....every time your app start again after closed, same routing happen

Answer (score 0):

In similar situation I used delegation pattern.

Assume you have your initial view controller initialVC. And special settings view controller (SetUpNav) which is meant to be run only first time when defaults is not set. Then you could do the following:

1. You define SetUpNavdelegate protocol in SetUpNavViewController.h and property "initiator" conforming to that protocol

> ```
> @protocol SetUpNavDeleagte;
>
> @interface SetUpNavViewController : UIViewController
> @property (strong,nonatomic) id <SetUpNavdelegate> initiator;
> // the rest
> @end
> @protocol SetUpNavdelegate <NSObject>
> -(void)setupFinished;
> @end
> ```

1. In your InitialVC' viewDidLoad you do:

   - Check Your defaults are set properly or not by determine "firstTime" BOOL value

and fire setUpNav  controller in code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Check your defaults for consistency
    if (firstTime){
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main OR you SB name" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *setUpNavVC = [loginStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SetUpNav"];
        setUpNavVC.initiator = self;
        YouAppDelegateClass *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        appDelegate.window.rootViewController = setUpVC;
        // Here you don't need animation as I assume it is the very first screen
    }
    // ... the rest
}


-(void)setupFinished
{
    // Here You animately restoring your initial vc.
    YouAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self; // This line is for device orientation sync
    [UIView transitionWithView:appDelegate.window
                      duration:FINISH_DURATION
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                    animations:^{ appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self; }
                    completion:nil];
     // setUpNav controller will be dealloced by ARC
}
```

1. In your setUpNavViewController after you finished all defaults job you set notification for your delegation:

> ```
> [self.initator setupFinished];
> ```

In may app this setting work is actually a separate storyboard with it's own workflow in it. By the way using this approach you are able not only show it first time but whenever your app's user defaults is not set properly (like if you using settings bundle). You can show it modally, in navigation stack or in pop over (iPad case). It is a more generic approach.

Summary: The one who starts, he finishes.